# Trigger event on change in returned data from getJSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I have an getJSON function which I'm currently calling once, and then with the setInterval() function, to listen to a thingspeak.com channel feed which could change values at any time.

I want to trigger an event in my jQuery code, outside the getJSON function, when the value of the returned data field1 is '1'. If the value is '0' it should turn the event off. So far, so good. But since the getJSON is listening to the channel feed a few seconds apart, it will fire the event (timer() function) over and over again.

How can I have the getJSON event "running in the background" and only fire when the returned data from the channel feed has actually changed? The data returned also has a field with the unique id for the data entry (entry_id), so it could be possible to listen for changes of this value.

Currently running this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    getUpdates();
    setInterval('getUpdates()',400);
});

function getUpdates() {
    $.getJSON('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/xxx/feed/last.json?callback=?', {key: "xxx"}, function(data) {
    if(data.field1 == '1') {
        // trigger timer function on
    } else if(data.field1 == '0') {
        // trigger timer function off
    }
});

function timer() {
    // Starts a timer countdown in a div
}
```

**Here's a second version of the code which may be more informative:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getUpdates();
    setInterval('getUpdates()',400);    
});

function getUpdates() {
    var entries = new Array();
    $.getJSON('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/xxx/feed/last.json?callback=?', {key: "xxx"}, function(data) {
        if ($.inArray(data.entry_id,entries) === -1) {
            //New entry, add the ID to the entries array
            entries.push(data.entry_id);

            //Check if the div should be visible or not
            if(data.field1 == '1') {
                $(".desc").show();
            } else if(data.field1 == '0') {
                $(".desc").hide();
            } 
        } else if ($.inArray(data.entry_id,entries) > -1) {
            // Same entry as previous call, do nothing.
        } 
    });
}

<div class="desc"></div>
```

This still does not work as it seems it does not update the entries array.

Comment: Your logic doesn't make sense to me. If data field is 1 - call `timer()`, if data is 0 - call `timer()`. When would you **not** want to trigger the `timer()` function?

Comment: Totally agree with dalbaeb. Your logic doens't make sense to me either. Every 400 milliseconds you check to see if the json object has changed. If it did change you wan't to trigger a timer, if it did not change you want to stop the timer. Which means your timer will only run for 400 milliseconds, because the getUpdates() interval keeps checking for changes every 400 milliseconds. Can you explain more about what this timer is going to do?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You point directly to my problem @Wezelkrozum, and it could be I'm going about this wrong. If data.field1 equals 1, I want to start a timer that should run for a minute. If the value of field1 in that time has changed to 0, I want to stop the timer. The problem now is that the code sets of a new timer each 400 ms, when I only want it to do it the first time field1 is set to 1 and then again after field1 has been set to 0 and then to 1 again. Does that make sense?

Comment: @dalbaeb, I've added some more code that may be more informative on what I want to attain?

Comment: @user1376918 what's a more high-level description of the problem? You're checking the feed (every 400ms), and depending on the value it returns you want to show/hide a div. What's the 1-minute "timer" for? Looks like you'd possibly need two `setIntervals`.

Comment: @dalbaeb The data returned from the feed is based on a users interaction (field1 sets to 0/1). The timer is set to count down from 1 minute after the user has 'switched' something on. If the user switched it off within that time (field1=0 from the feed), the timer should also be stopped and give a feedback to the user. If not the timer should continue to count downwards. What would I need the other setIntervals for?

Comment: @user1376918 and if within that 1-minute interval the user switches it off and instantly on again, what happens then? the 1-minute timer is restarted?

Comment: @dalbaeb After the feedback message, it should be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approximate, untested logic (after all I don't have access to the feed with correct data). Let me know if it steers you in the right direction.

```
var timerSet = 0;

function startTimer(){
    timerSet = 1;
    // start the 1-minute timer and show feedback to user
}

function stopTimer(){
    timerSet = 0;
    // stop the 1-minute timer and show feedback to user
}

function getUpdates() {
    var entries = new Array();
    $.getJSON('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/xxx/feed/last.json?callback=?', {key: "xxx"}, function(data) {
        if ($.inArray(data.entry_id,entries) === -1) {
            //New entry, add the ID to the entries array
            entries.push(data.entry_id);

            // check which state the system is in and manage the 1-minute timer
            if(data.field1 == '1' && timerSet === 0) { // if 1-minute timer not running already - start it
                startTimer();
            } else if(data.field1 == '0' && timerSet === 1) { // if 1-minute timer running already - stop it
                stopTimer();
            } 
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // getUpdates(); don't need this: function will be called in 400ms anyway
    setInterval('getUpdates()',400);    
});
```